# How to evaluate xml with namespaces in office add ins?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, office-js, office-2016

I'm trying to search for particular nodes in office xml. I'm using wgxpath for it. Here is my code. But every time empty result is returned. Probably [wgxpath doesn't work with namespaces](https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath/issues/7) (although it accepts nsResolver as parameter)

```
Word.run(function (ctx) {
    var xml = ctx.document.body.getOoxml();
    ctx.sync().then(function () {
        try {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
            var win = { 'document': doc };
            wgxpath.install(win);
            var nsResolver = doc.createNSResolver(doc.ownerDocument == null ? doc.documentElement : doc.ownerDocument.documentElement);
            var result = doc.evaluate("/pkg:package/pkg:part/pkg:xmlData/w:styles/w:docDefaults/w:pPrDefault/w:pPr/w:spacing", doc, nsResolver, win.XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
            var items = [];
            try {
                var item = result.iterateNext();
                while (item) {
                    items.push(item);
                    item = result.iterateNext();
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
        resolve(items);
    });
});
```

I've also tried another example with simple xml:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var test = "<pkg:count xmlns:pkg='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage'><pkg:a>1</pkg:a></pkg:count>";
var doc = parser.parseFromString(test, "text/xml");
var win = { 'document': doc };
wgxpath.install(win);
var nsResolver = function(prefix) {
    var ns = {
        'pkg': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage'
    };
    return ns[prefix] || null;
}
var result = doc.evaluate('/pkg:count/pkg:a', doc, nsResolver, win.XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Result is the same: with prefixes empty result is returned, but if I remove prefixes, evaluation works.

How can I evaluate xml with namespaces in office add ins? Any other solution? I've tried to use ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"), but get "Can't create object" exception.

Answer (score 0):

The built in XML parsing methods do support namespaces, but not xpath.

E.g. [Document.getElementsByTagNameNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagNameNS)